# How to find the number of functions, stored procedures in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

How can I find the number of User-defined functions and Stored Procedures in PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 1):

It will work for you :

(editted by @a_horse_with_no_name 's warn)

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE routines.specific_schema='schema_name'
```

Comment: oohh you are so right. I am editing the answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This excludes metadata schemas of postgres:

```
select count(*) from information_schema.routines t where t.routine_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

If you're only interested in the number of procedures then:

```
select count(*) from information_schema.routines t where t.routine_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') and t.routine_type = 'PROCEDURE';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the list of procedures and functions with schema then you can use

```
SELECT specific_schema,routine_name, routine_type
FROM information_schema.routines
where specific_schema ='Schema_name'
```

and if you want just a count of procedures and functions then you can use

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.routines
where specific_schema ='Schema_name'
```